# R: Using doBy with Dates

Tags: r, date, sequence, summarize, autonumber

I am doing some coding in R.  I am trying to use the doBy package to get a sum total score for a variable (x) by both date (date) and by id (id).  The doBy command works fine and I get this output.

```
data
id date       x
1  01/01/2021 1
1  01/02/2021 2
1  01/03/2021 3
2  02/01/2021 2
2  02/02/2021 3
2  02/02/2021 4
3  03/11/2021 3
3  03/12/2021 3
3  03/13/2021 2
```

I want to recode the date so that everyone's first chronological date 1 is 1, the chronological second date is 2, the chronological 3rd date is 3, etc.  I want my date to look something like this.

```
data2
id daycount x
1  1        1
1  2        2
1  3        3
2  1        2
2  2        3
2  3        4
3  1        3
3  2        3
3  3        2
```

I was able to order the days using order() but I am not sure how to get the dates to match up.  I think I need some kind of sequence or autonumber.  Also, some participants may have different number of days.  Some participants may have 1 day and other participants may have 10 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) doBy** Assuming that the dates are already sorted within id:

```
library(doBy)
transform_by(data, ~ id, countdays = seq_along(id))
```

giving:

```
  id       date x countdays
1  1 01/01/2021 1         1
2  1 01/02/2021 2         2
3  1 01/03/2021 3         3
4  2 02/01/2021 2         1
5  2 02/02/2021 3         2
6  2 02/02/2021 4         3
7  3 03/11/2021 3         1
8  3 03/12/2021 3         2
9  3 03/13/2021 2         3
```

**2) Base R** It could also be done using transform and ave in base R.

```
transform(data, daycount = ave(id, id, FUN = seq_along))
```

giving:

```
  id       date x daycount
1  1 01/01/2021 1        1
2  1 01/02/2021 2        2
3  1 01/03/2021 3        3
4  2 02/01/2021 2        1
5  2 02/02/2021 3        2
6  2 02/02/2021 4        3
7  3 03/11/2021 3        1
8  3 03/12/2021 3        2
9  3 03/13/2021 2        3
```

### Note

`data` in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "id date       x
1  01/01/2021 1
1  01/02/2021 2
1  01/03/2021 3
2  02/01/2021 2
2  02/02/2021 3
2  02/02/2021 4
3  03/11/2021 3
3  03/12/2021 3
3  03/13/2021 2"
data <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will be sure to include sample code to reproduce my data for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `group_by` by `id` and then create a new column using `rank` or `dense_rank` (note the difference with them with handling the duplicates).

To recreate your data, I used:

```
# recreate data frame
id_vec <- rep(c(1,2,3), each = 3)
date_vec <- c(
  '01/01/2021',
  '01/02/2021',
  '01/03/2021',
  '02/01/2021',
  '02/02/2021',
  '02/02/2021',
  '03/11/2021',
  '03/12/2021',
  '03/13/2021' 
)
x_vec <- rep(c(1,2,3), times = 3)
data <- data.frame(id = id_vec, date = date_vec, x = x_vec)
```

I also converted the `data` column to an actual date format for your convenience:

```
# convert string to date object
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% mutate(date_formatted = mdy(date))
```

Creating a column with `rank`:

```
data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(day_count = rank(date_formatted, ties.method = "first")) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 9 x 5
# id date           x date_formatted day_count
# <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <date>             <int>
# 1     1 01/01/2021     1 2021-01-01             1
# 2     1 01/02/2021     2 2021-01-02             2
# 3     1 01/03/2021     3 2021-01-03             3
# 4     2 02/01/2021     1 2021-02-01             1
# 5     2 02/02/2021     2 2021-02-02             2
# 6     2 02/02/2021     3 2021-02-02             3
# 7     3 03/11/2021     1 2021-03-11             1
# 8     3 03/12/2021     2 2021-03-12             2
# 9     3 03/13/2021     3 2021-03-13             3
```

Creating new column with `dense_rank`:

```
data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(day_count = dense_rank(date_formatted)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 9 x 5
# id date           x date_formatted day_count
# <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <date>             <int>
# 1     1 01/01/2021     1 2021-01-01             1
# 2     1 01/02/2021     2 2021-01-02             2
# 3     1 01/03/2021     3 2021-01-03             3
# 4     2 02/01/2021     1 2021-02-01             1
# 5     2 02/02/2021     2 2021-02-02             2
# 6     2 02/02/2021     3 2021-02-02             2
# 7     3 03/11/2021     1 2021-03-11             1
# 8     3 03/12/2021     2 2021-03-12             2
# 9     3 03/13/2021     3 2021-03-13             3
```